# Gráfica sobre matriz a partir de dos listas

Tags: python, imagen, matrices, matplotlib

Hola y gracias de antemano.

Tengo una matriz de tamaño x,y como la siguiente:

[image: p]

Y además tengo dos listas relacionadas entre sí, p y q. Cada punto de las listas me da una posición en la matriz mostrada antes.

Para que os hagáis una idea, al hacer print(p) y print(q) me da como resultado:

print(p) = [ 1 1 2 ... 5159 5160 5161]
len(p) = 10155

print(q) = [0 1 1 ... 4994 4994 4994]
len(q) = 10155

Lo que necesito es dibujar las coordenadas de manera que quede una linea con forma de escalera(ya que algunos valores se repiten sobre otros) sobre mi matriz.

He intentado realizar primero imshow(matriz) y después plt.plot(p[i], q[i]) en un bucle hasta la longitud de p, pero el resultado no es el esperado.

Si se necesita más información puedo añadirla.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Perdón por una respuesta con una solución tan sencilla, dejo por aquí la solución por si a alguien se le presenta este problema.

Cuando realizas el imshow(matriz) después bastará con utilizar plot(p,q) para obtener la línea que yo necesitaba. Dejo un ejemplo:
[image]